# FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION with both bitmap or bytearray

Tags: android, bitmap

First, I tried to pass a large image file between activities using Bitmap, but received the following error:

> E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 6560360)

I read a solution on SO to convert the Bitmap to a byte array first, so I tried it:

FirstActivity

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("photo",byteArray);
startActivity(i);
```

SecondActivity

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("photo");
Bitmap loopPhotoBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

But this gives the same error. How can I pass the image data between activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I pass the image data between activities?

You don't. Either:

- These should be combined into one activity, or
- You should have some sort of image cache that the two activities share, where you pass the identifier to the cache entry

Comment: You can point me in the direction of what type of caching to implement?

Comment: @Donato: I do not know where the image is coming from. If the image is coming from disk or the network, hopefully you are using an image-loading library (Glide, Picasso, etc.), and they have integrated caching.

Comment: I do not think combining activities is a good idea because if I was to use fragments, still it is difficult. This is like wizard with multiple steps that require a back button.

Comment: @Donato: "This is like wizard with multiple steps that require a back button" -- use either a `ViewPager` or a `RecyclerView` in a single activity. Or, use existing libraries for that UI pattern, that themselves will use `ViewPager` or a `RecyclerView` in a single activity.